# Cookie. CORS. Browser doesn`t set cookies if I submit form without preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, cookies

This is my code

```
import Helper from './helper'
import List from './itemList'
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

function getAlfrescoTicket(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //doesn`t set cookie with out it 
    let auth = {};
    auth.username = this.username.value;
    auth.password = this.password.value;
    let xhr = Helper.getXmlHttp();
    xhr.open("POST", List.ticketURL);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            Helper.setCookie('ticket', 
JSON.parse(this.responseText).data.ticket, 1);
            console.log(Helper.getCookie('ticket'));
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(auth));
}

myForm.addEventListener('submit', getAlfrescoTicket);
```

If I set cookie with e.preventDefault() cookies are set up, but my form doesn't sumbit and page doesn't change, because of e.preventDefault(), 
but if I don't use e.preventDefault(),  form works fine, page changes but cookies are absent. How to make cookies set up and page to load ?

Comment: `xhr.withCredentials = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add 
`myForm.submit()` in your function.

without `e.preventDefault` the form submits before your code has finished, when you do `e.preventDefault` your function runs but the native behavior of the browser with form submitting is not running obviously (you prevented the defaults! ) :) so you would need to submit it by yourself, one way to do that is described here.

Comment: it's aliiiiiiiive! Thanks dude, you're awesome!